# How to access methods in a class nested within an abstract class?

Tags: scala

UPDATE[SOLVED]: needed to put the gates outside of nested `Wire` class (thanks Dima).

EDIT: I'm not sure why I was downvoted for this question. This is a legit question because I'm taking the online coursera course in Reactive Programming by Martin Odersky, and if you go and look at lecture 3.6 "discrete event simulation implementation and test" yourself, you will see that Martin implemented the code exactly as I did and he did not get these errors. This was not an assignment, all code was presented and I simply copied it from the slides. You can see below screenshots from the actual video showing that the gates are written *inside* of Wire class.

[image]
[image]

I have an abstract class `Circuits` (in file Circuits.scala) which extends an abstract class `Gates`. Within `Gates` is defined a class `Wire` (both Gates and Wire are in file Gates.scala). And inside of this class `Wire` is defined several functions one of which is `orGate`. When I try to access `orGate` and other functions inside `Wire`, the IDE complains with `symbol not found`. What special thing do I need to do so that `orGate` etc. are visible from `Circuits`? Code snippets to illustrate my issue follows.

file Circuits.scala:

```
package week3      
abstract class Circuits extends Gates {

      def halfAdder(a: Wire, b: Wire, s: Wire, c: Wire) {
        val d, e = new Wire
        orGate(a, b, d)      // <--- symbol not found: orGate
        andGate(a, b, c)     // <---- symbol not found: andGate 
        inverter(c, e)       // <--- etc.
        andGate(d, e, s)
      }

      def fullAdder(a: Wire, b: Wire, cin: Wire, sum: Wire, cout: Wire) {
        val s, c1, c2 = new Wire
        halfAdder(a, cin, s, c1)
        halfAdder(b, s, sum, c2)
        orGate(c1, c2, cout)
      }

    }
```

file: Gates.scala:

```
package week3


abstract class Gates extends Simulation {

  def InverterDelay: Int
  def AndGateDelay: Int
  def OrGateDelay: Int

  class Wire {

    private var sigVal = false
    private var actions: List[Action] = List()

    def getSignal: Boolean = sigVal
    def setSignal(s: Boolean): Unit = {
      if (s != sigVal) {
        sigVal = s
        actions foreach (_())
      }
    }
    def addAction(a: Action): Unit = {
      actions = a::actions
      a()
    }

    def inverter(input: Wire, output: Wire): Unit = {
      def invertAction(): Unit = {
        val inputSig = input.getSignal
        afterDelay(InverterDelay) { output setSignal !inputSig}
      }
      input addAction invertAction
    }


    def andGate(in1: Wire, in2: Wire, output: Wire): Unit = {
      def andAction(): Unit = {
        val in1Sig = in1.getSignal
        val in2Sig = in2.getSignal
        afterDelay(AndGateDelay) {output setSignal (in1Sig & in2Sig)}
      }

      in1 addAction andAction
      in2 addAction andAction
    }


    def orGate(in1: Wire, in2: Wire, output: Wire): Unit = {
      def orAction(): Unit = {
        val in1Sig = in1.getSignal
        val in2Sig = in2.getSignal
        afterDelay(OrGateDelay) {output setSignal (in1Sig | in2Sig)}
      }

      in1 addAction orAction
      in2 addAction orAction
    }

    def probe(name: String, wire: Wire): Unit = {
      def probeAction(): Unit = {
        println(name, currentTime, wire.getSignal)
      }
      wire addAction probeAction
    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`orGate` and most other things, except `addAction` and `setSignal` should be defined outside of `Wire`.

Also, you really writing java code here (albeit in scala syntax). I encourage you to find a book or online resource on scala and read through the first few chapters to familiarize yourself with the basic concepts and paradigms of the language.

Comment: I copied this code wholesale from the slides of a course on Coursera and the lecturer was able to run the code as-is.

Comment: Well, he was, you aren't ... what does it tell you about your code copying skills? ;)

Comment: so do you take back your comment that ```orGate``` and most other things should be defined outside of ```Wire```, or do you still stand by it?

Comment: @thetrystero I stand by it. 
I have no idea what you copied from where, but the code you posted here is wrong in the way I described.

Comment: OK fair enough. I'll take the hit on this one. It's probably just too late here. Thanks.